# Rails 4 displays white screen instead of displaying a 500/400 errors page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I have a Rails 4.2.3 app with the following configuration in staging:

```
...
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
...
```

Somehow if a get a 404 or 500 error from the server, instead of seeing the standard Rails error page I get a blank page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a 404.html in your public folder?

Comment: Yup, I also have 422.html and 500.html

Comment: What do your console logs say when you get a 404 response? Can you post it?

Comment: what gems you're using apart from your usual ones, sounds to me it might be related to a gem